# Lendo arquivo properties

Tags: java, android

Como faço para ler dados de um arquivo `properties` no Android?
Segue meu código do `onCreate`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    File file = new File(getPackageName()+ "/dados.properties");
    Properties pp = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {       
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        pp.load(fis);
        fis.close();
    } catch (Exception e) { }
}
```

Sempre dá erro no `fis = new FileInputStream(file);`.

Comment: Informe qual é o erro que está ocorrendo. Provavelmente é devido ao caminho para o arquivo não ter sido encontrado. Pesquise sobre como obter o diretório do aplicativo (onde você provavelmente quer guardar o arquivo de propriedades), por exemplo [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527764/get-application-directory).

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo colocar o arquivo `dados.properties` na pasta `res/raw`. Colocando nessa pasta você consegue obter um `InputStream` para qualquer arquivo desta pasta com esse código:

```
public InputStream readRaw(Context context, int rawResId) {
    return context.getResources().openRawResource(rawResId);
}
```

Se quiser mais detalhes de uma olhada na documentação do [`Resources.openRawResource(int id)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource%28int%29)

Encaixando no seu código ficaria como:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Properties pp = new Properties();

    try {
        pp.load(readRaw(this, R.raw.dados));
    } catch (Exception e) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O caminho que você está buscando não é esse. Dê uma olhada na função [getFilesDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29), ela vai retornar o caminho dos arquivos da sua aplicação (/data/data/seupacote).

Tente algo do tipo:

```
File file = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/dados.properties");
```